# IdentityServer4 - Inject ConfigurationDbContext for use in class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am persisting configuration in the `ConfigurationDbContext`.  I am now creating a ServiceProvider that will allow to dynamically add Clients, ApiResources, etc. at a later time.

My question is, what is the best way to retrieve the `ConfigurationDbContext` in a class?  If dependency injection is the best answer, how do I register the `ConfigurationDbContext` as a service, and how do I retrieve that service from a class outside of `Startup.cs` where `IApplicationBuilder.ApplicationServices` is not available?

Comment: Probably this link may be helpful for you. http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html

Comment: I've looked at this link. It doesn't describe how to do this

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you do it once you define ConfigurationDbContext.

1. In Startup.cs file register ConfigurationDbContext as follows.

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
      string connectionString = "my connection string";

      services.AddEntityFramework()
               .AddSqlServer()
               .AddDbContext<ConfigurationDbContext>(options => 
               options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

       //Add more services here e.g.
       services.AddMvc();
   }
   ```
2. Use ConfigurationDbContext wherever its needed.

   ```
   public class MyClassWhereDbContextIsNeeded
   {
      private readonly ConfigurationDbContext dbContext;

      //Inject context instance here.
      public MyClassWhereDbContextIsNeeded(ConfigurationDbContext dbContext)
      {
         this.dbContext = dbContext;
      }

      public void SomeMethod()
      {
         //Use DbContext here e.g. Get customers from database.
         var customers =  dbContext.Customers.ToList());
      }
    }
   ```

Comment: But when/if I need to create an instance of MyClassWhereDbContextIsNeeded, don't I still need to provide provide an instance? Also, ideally I would like to create a new instance of the Dbcontext within a method of that class, so I can do a unit of work and dispose of it

Comment: Ideally you will be registering  MyClassWhereDbContextIsNeeded as one of dependency and injecting it wherever MyClassWhereDbContextIsNeeded instance is needed. Whole idea of dependency injection is reducing tight coupling by injecting dependencies rather creating instances explicitly within code. Your DI container will be taking care of creating/destroying instances based on how you have registered dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.  My confusion here is that I have a class called `RoleService`, and it has methods like "AddRole", "DeleteRole", etc.  I want each one of these methods to retrieve a DbContext in their body.